# How to authenticate Jenkins & Amazon EKS

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, pkcs#12, amazon-eks, aws-iam-authenticator

I'm having an issue on integrating Jenkins kubernetes plugin with Amazon EKS. In Jenkins plugin, which asks to provide a PKCS12 file and get connected, but in my case, I've used aws-iam-authenticator to communicate with Amazon EKS API. There is no option to add any token authentication in Jenkins config side. Further I tried to connect create a PKCS12 file, only I had ca.crt, but how can I find -inkey client.key & -in client.crt ? It's bit confusing me. Can anyone help me? I've tried following command.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt -vertfile ca.crt
```

Or else can anyone help me on other alternative how I can authenticate Jenkins and Amazon EKS?

Thanks.

Comment: does this help https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#running-with-a-remote-kubernetes-cloud-in-aws-eks ?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta I've gone through the document you shared, which expains the JNLP pods configurations, but I need how to do the authentication part with Amazon EKS, as in normal way, we use aws-iam-authenticator, so like that I need to get an idea how I can authenticate Jenkins with Kubernetes.